# I have a problem with websocket (PlayFramework) under stress test

Tags: spring, websocket, playframework

I created a microservice, which uses websockets using Playframework 2.6.

I decided  to do the stress test for result 101 (Switching Protocols).

When I doing 20-30 RPS, then it works Ok. But, if I am doing more then 30,then I get 46% errors:

> Unmasked client frame(error of protocol).

I want to note that the web service developed on Spring Reactive works  without problems under the given conditions. Why is this happening?

I want to tell about my conclusion.PlayFramework opens first 1000 websocket connection without a problem and when I want to open next connection Playframework closes open connection .And I got next result:1000-ok 2000 - error 3000 -ok 4000 - error.I had tested web-chat on Spring Reactive WebSocket and I did not see the such problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I accept your change.Thank you.

Comment: You could consider writing up a nice self answer. That comment alone won't be of much help for future readers.